# Supplying 4 V (max 3 A) to my circuit using lithium-ion batteries

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, boost

I'm designing a circuit for a portable device, and the main component requires 4 V (±5%) up to 3 A (12 W). The 3 A is the *max* for the circuit- typical load is 250 mA.

As I understand, the voltage range for 3.7 V lithium-ion batteries is about 2.8-4.2 V depending on their charge level. At maximum charge, 4.2 V is within the ±5% tolerance for the 4 V component; However, at minimum charge, I understand I'll need a boost converter to adequately supply the necessary 4 V.

Since the 3 A maximum is quite high, I understand that I'll likely need to use a *pair* of lithium batteries in parallel to prevent voltage drop or battery damage under high load.

There seems to be no off-the-shelf options for a fixed 4 V boost converter capable of 3 A. I considered using 6 parallel 500 mA fixed 4 V boost converters instead. Alternatively, should I consider designing my own boost converter circuit to achieve this instead? Can I be sure that a circuit I design myself will not fry the 4 V component, for example, whenever I connect a charger? Can I be sure the voltage will not drop below 4 V (±5%) if the load is increased suddenly?

Additionally, will I need to ensure that my charging circuit is capable of keeping up with this demand as well, or can I use a less-powerful charging circuit with the understanding that it will actually *deplete* the batteries while charging under high load?

Comment: Charging  Li-ion batteries while trying to use them is a sure way of overcharging them and causing overheating and possibly fire or explosion. Your supply really needs to be able to power your load separately to charging the battery.

Answer (score 0):

Use a buck-boost converter. It can output 4 V when it receives a wired range of input voltages, below and above 4 V.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use two or more cells in series and then a buck converter, as the battery voltage will always be higher than the output voltage.  This may be preferable to buck-boost as the circuit is simpler and typically more efficient.  If you’re using 18650 cells then 3A shouldn’t be a problem in any case, but certainly check the datasheet for the cells you want to use.